# MQTT runs over TCP/IP

Tags: tcp, protocols, mqtt, iot

It is stated that MQTT usually runs over TCP/IP. I found a figure below and I was confused.

[image: TCP/IP layers and IoT Protocol]

I know that TCP/IP is a set of communications protocols, but not only means 'TCP' and "IP' these two protocols.
Then what is the meaning of MQTT 'run over' TCP/IP? Can I say that the three-way handshake , retransmission, and error-detection of TCP allows ordered, lossless connections of MQTT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then what is the meaning of MQTT 'run over' TCP/IP?

The table in your post is actually a presentation of the [OSI-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). In that model there are layers of protocols, where protocols of a layer rely on protocols from layers below. So the MQTT (layer 7) relies ('run over') on TCP/IP stack (layer 6 and below).

> can I interpret that the 'other network protocols that provide
> ordered, lossless, bi-directional connections' which MQTT runs over
> are the protocols not included in TCP/IP models?

Yes. Zigbee, for example.

> can I say that the three-way handshake , retransmission, and
> error-detection of TCP allows ordered, lossless connections of MQTT?

Well, "ordered, lossless connections" are probably ensured not only by features of TCP, but also by mechanisms belonging to MQTT protocol itself.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is wrong, the blue `TCP` on the Internet line should read `IP`

And to answer your question please read the MQTT [Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html), e.g. from the MQTT 3.1.1 spec, abstract second paragraph

> The protocol runs over TCP/IP, or over other network protocols that provide ordered, lossless, bi-directional connections.

Comment: In the MQTT Specification section 4.2, it is mentioned that the transport protocol used to carry MQTT was TCP/IP as defined in [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html#section-2.6), but this document only introduces TCP. Does it mean that MQTT runs over 'TCP' and 'IP' in TCP/IP model?  Besides, can I interpret that the 'other network protocols that provide ordered, lossless, bi-directional connections' which MQTT runs over are the protocols not included in TCP/IP models? Thanks!

Comment: The quote is pretty clear, I don't know how to explain it any clearer. MQTT normally runs over TCP, which in turn normally runs over IP (but doesn't have to). It can also run on any other network layer that meets the requirements mentioned (e.g. Not UDP)

Comment: "bi-directional connections" means full duplex, right? Something similar to websockets where the broker is able to maintain open channels with all the clients/servers.

Comment: MQTT over websockets is an existing implementation supported by many brokers